# Template template class with enum specification fails on MSVC++ Compiler: C3201

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, c++11, template-templates

## Code

Here is the [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) example of my problem:

```
// My Library, which I want to take in the user's enum and a template class which they put per-enum specialized code
template <typename TEnum, template <TEnum> class EnumStruct>
struct LibraryT { /* Library stuff */ };

// User Defined Enum and Associated Template (which gets specialized later)
namespace MyEnum {
    enum Enum {
        Value1 /*, ... */
    };
};

template <MyEnum::Enum>
struct MyEnumTemplate {};

template <>
struct MyEnumTemplate<MyEnum::Value1> { /* specialized code here */ };

// Then the user wants to use the library:
typedef LibraryT<MyEnum::Enum, MyEnumTemplate> MyLibrary;

int main() {
    MyLibrary library;
}
```

[**EDIT**: Changing `LibraryT<MyEnum::Enum, MyEnumTemplate>` to `LibraryT<typename MyEnum::Enum, MyEnumTemplate>` has no effect]

## Error

The functionality I desire is the ability to create a library based on an enum and a class which is specialized by that enum.  Above is my first attempt.  I believe it is 100% C++, and GCC backs me up and says it all works.  However, I want it to compile with the MSVC++ Compiler and it refuses:

```
error C3201: the template parameter list for class template 'MyEnumTemplate' 
  does not match the template parameter list for template parameter 'EnumStruct'
```

## Question

Is there some way I can make the MSVC++ compiler [**EDIT**: MSVC++ 11 Compiler (VS 2012)] like my code?  Either by some addition specifications or different approach?

## Possible (but undesirable) Solution

Hard code the enum type to be some integral type (the underlying type).  Then no problems.  But then my library is operating on integrals instead of the enum type (undesirable, but working)

```
// My Library, which I want to take in the user's enum and a template class which they put per-enum specialized code
typedef unsigned long IntegralType; // **ADDED**

template <template <IntegralType> class EnumStruct> // **CHANGED**
struct LibraryT { /* Library stuff */ };

// User Defined Enum and Associated Template (which gets specialized later)
namespace MyEnum {
    enum Enum {
        Value1 /*, ... */
    };
};

template <IntegralType> // **CHANGED**
struct MyEnumTemplate {};

template <>
struct MyEnumTemplate<MyEnum::Value1> {};

// Then the user wants to use the library:
typedef LibraryT<MyEnumTemplate> MyLibrary; // **CHANGED**

int main() {
    MyLibrary library;
}
```

Comment: In case it ends up being pertinent, VC++ 2010 or 2012?

Comment: @idjarn The most recent one: The MSVC++ 11 Compiler (it is included in VS 2012)

Comment: @ahenderson I believe in this case the `typename` part is optional, adding it does not make a difference

Comment: I haven't looked at the code in-depth so I don't know if this is relevant, but it might be worth noting that MSVC hasn't fully implemented C++11 yet.  So if your code is relying on C++11 features, it might be worth checking if MSVC has actually implemented the relevant features.  Even if it has, this is newer stuff so the likelihood of compiler bugs is greater than 'usual'.

Comment: @WeirdlyCheezy I believe it is a compiler bug, but I am looking for a way to achieve the same result, but avoid the bug.  I am pretty sure the template-template implementation in MSVC++ 11 is a little wonky.

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question; I'm still trying to wrap my head around the intended semantics.  Are you trying to specialize MyLibrary based on the enum as a group of values, or against a specific value of the enum?  That is, the end of your example code, when you typedef MyLibrary, did you mean something like:  typedef LibraryT<MyEnum::Enum::Value1, MyEnumTemplate> MyLibrary;

Comment: @WeirdlyCheezy I wanted to template based on an enum type (not the value). I want an instance of MyLibrary for every set of enums a developer wants, not an instance for each value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known bug in the Visual C++ compiler.  See the following bug on Microsoft Connect for more information (the repro is slightly different, but the issue is effectively the same):

> [C++ compiler bug - cannot use template parameters inside nested template declaration](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/655445/c-compiler-bug-cannot-use-template-parameters-inside-nested-template-declaration)

The recommended workaround is to use an integer type for the template parameter of the template template parameter, which is what you have done in your "possible (but undesirable) solution."